# How to debug, test php? How to test html with .html removed (.htaccess)?

Tags: php, html, debugging, testing

**I'm wondering how professional web developers debug, test, and deploy websites with some specific questions.**

**#1 PHP**

For a big site like amazon.com, I imagine they don't upload to the server to test php code. So how do they do it?

**Is there a software or IDE I could use to test php locally?**

**#2 debugging without .html .php extension?**

In addition, most sites remove .html and .php in url
I'm also doing this by editing .htaccess

```
# remove .html .php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

But when I do this, I need to reference other html and php files without adding the extension

```
<a href="about">About</a>
<a href="contact">Contact</a>
```

So then I can't debug locally, since links won't work without uploading

**How can I debug locally with this specific .htaccess?**

**How do other sites do it?**

Any tips or general practices on website debugging, deployment, and testing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick solution: XAMPP

First off, your question is very broad, especially at the end. These are impossible to answer correctly. I will address the two clear-cut questions you pose. For broad, in-depth knowledge you will need to read up on the stuff that interests you.

In the case of PHP, you can run a web server and PHP interpreter locally, i.e. on your development computer. Like always, there are many ways to go about this. A very simple way is to install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/).

You will then use the web browser and instead of the actual domain go to a localhost address, i.e. one provided by your own computer.

This will also allow you to use the same settings, such as the URL rewriting rules you listed, because the Apache web server you're currently using is the `A` in XAMPP.

---

#### Environment similarity

A general theme you may already sense is to have a separate development environment which should be as similar to the production environment as possible. Similarity includes the entire software stack (OS, libraries, web server, external software) including their exact versions, and may also extend to the hardware. Similarity is good because it gives you predictability. Stuff will still go wrong, but not because of a different PHP version.

This may mean having separate servers (virtual or not) dedicated for the development process.

In the case of XAMPP your personal computer will act as a development server. As regards similarity, it may be difficult to match your local development environment exactly to the server.

#### Separate development instance on same server

Another simple strategy in your situation would be to run a copy of your project on the same server as you use for production. Don't tell anyone about the development copy, and add basic-auth to protect the directory. Then use this to develop & test without fear of breaking the production instance.

This would guarantee exactly the same software & hardware conditions, but has the disadvantage of not being a local development server. And, if you need to make bigger changes, they will affect the prod instance as well.

#### Development VM

If you're feeling a bit adventurous, you could spin up a Virtual Machine that provides a web server on the OS of your choice, and again similar to your production server (often Linux). This is a local solution, but you have much more control over the software stack and you can't break production.

This freedom comes with a lot of work making things run smoothly. You will learn a boatload.

---

I also feel obligated to mention that there are many other programming languages and frameworks to make websites server-side. Java, Python, .NET, JavaScript just to name a few.

Comment: I appreciate your answer so mcuh

Comment: I think testing and debugging with XAMPP is a great choice for a small, personal project but I would go with creating a test site on the same server for bigger or group projects. And to add security, I could add an admin page for viewing test sites. I'm guessing this is a good scalable approach. Thank you so much